# Opening PDF's using `target="blank"` fails on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, pdf

I have a bunch of PDF links that open in new tabs. On Desktop, this works perfectly.

However, when using a mobile phone (only tested on Samsung Galaxy's), the PDF links just open a new tab for a split second, then close without downloading the file.

```html
<a href="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" target="_blank">
  Open PDF
</a> 
(this just quickly opens and closes a new tab when using Chrome on my Samsung Android)
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/3w7ho1mx/) | [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/full/oNGGwjJ)

How can I allow users to open files in a new tab on Desktop and just download them on Mobile? (Preferably, only using HTML)

Note: removing `target="_blank"` does not solve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240400/discussion-between-chris-happy-and-k-j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make the URL relative to the site domain**

```html
<a href="/sample.pdf" target="_blank">Open PDF</a> 
<!-- Not <a href="/example.com/sample.pdf>Open PDF</a> -->
```

This allowed the links to download without issue on the Google Chrome app (specifically on Samsung).

Answer (score 2):

You should better display pdf in mobile browser via Google Doc Viewer:

```
http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=<url of your doc>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution An! It also works, but still doesn't allow me to download the file (even with `https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=<...>`) and creates a dependency on Google. Will keep it as a last resort :)

Comment: this also can work on android apps which tries to open pdf in google custom tabs, just save the link in strings resources this way -> `http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&amp;url=<url>your-pdf-file.pdf</url>` and it will open normally in google custom tabs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was wondering why the selected answer was working.
The point is not the relative/absolute URL, but the fact that you are trying to open a static resource on HTTP starting from a website that is probably under HTTP**S** . Using relative urls magically do just the same.

I solved by corrected the links forcing HTTPS on the PDF I needed to open.